# TFS/VSTS: Reference custom variables by group

Tags: tfs

I want to use a variable defined in a variable group in one of my Release Definitions. I know, that I have to add the group to the definition.

Is it possible to explicitely reference a variable by its group? Just like:

```
$(MyGroup.myVar)
```

Background: I have multiple variable groups, all containing a variable with the same name. I wand to distinguish between the variable of group **A** and the variable of group **B**.

I'm currently using an on-premise TFS 2017 Update 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, we can't reference a variable by its group directly such as `$(MyGroup.myVar)` , It's not supported.

You have to set different variables in different variable groups. Then reference them in release definitions. See [Variable groups](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/library/variable-groups).

If there are the same variables in different linked variable groups. The process will use the variable which set in the first linked group.

Anyway, that's a good idea in release definition practice, I have submitted a [**user voice**](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/20367913-tfs2017-vsts-reference-custom-variables-by-group) for this feature, you can go and vote it up for achieving it in future.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your requirement is to use different variable groups in different environments. If that assumption is accurate, then you can now use environment scoped variable groups to achieve just this. See my answer in another thread for overview: [Is there a way to use VSTS Variable Groups per environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014162/is-there-a-way-to-use-vsts-variable-groups-per-environment/48578601#48578601)