# Is there a way to use VSTS Variable Groups per environment?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm moving my configuration from using web.config transforms to being based on VSTS variables.  I get process variables, you define a variable, pick an environment, and you're good to go.  I also see "Variable Groups", these seem great, have KeyVault integration, and overall seem like a much better option.

But...I don't see a way to bind a Variable Group to a specific environment in my VSTS release process.  I can't honestly see how these would be any use to me without this feature.

I've experimented with one workaround, but it didn't work.  I tried:

- Naming my variable group & variables with an environment prefix e.g.

  - Variable Group Name="Production ConnectionStrings"
  - Variable name="Production_LoggingConnectionString"
  - I thought once I linked the "Production_ConnectionStrings" variable, I could reference $(Production_LoggingConnectionString) from within a standard Process variable, but this didn't work.

I think I could come up with some powershell that would do something like the above and set variables, but this seems a bit too custom for me.

Does anyone else have an idea that I can use variable groups per environment, easily, without waiting around for VSTS to build this feature (if ever).  Btw, if you want this feature, there is a suggestion here you can upvote:  [Make it possible to link a variable group to a specific environment in a release definition](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19056559-make-it-possible-to-link-a-variable-group-to-a-spe)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has now been implemented in VSTS variable groups as scopes. Go to your release definition -> Variables -> Variable Groups -> Link variable group, and you get the link window as below, where you can choose the scope to be either release or one or more of your environments!

[image]

I did not manage to find any release information on this feature, I just stumbled upon it as I was tweaking my releases.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for sharing.  I had no idea they were even working on the feature based on the roadmap, and lack of Microsoft action on that Uservoice.

Comment: This setting is available for Release pipelines definitions but not available to Build definitions.

Comment: @gabe The whole concept of environments is missing from the build pipeline, so I don't see how this feature could be there? Anyway, the idea should be to build once, and deploy multiple times to different environments. If you have a requirement that can't be satisfied by this principle, maybe you aught to open a separate question on that, and we'll see if we can guide you to an appropriate outcome!

Comment: @TuukkaHaapaniemi My use case is integration testing with resources like CosmosDB and Event Hubs where I need to add connection strings to the test environment. Variable groups allow for a nice way to store secrets like those.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using a powershell script to define my process variable based on the variable groups, it works great.

Let's say I want a variable named "LoggingConnectionString" and this has different values per environment

Steps:

1. Define a Variable group, e.g. "SharedLoggingVariables"
2. Inside this Variable group, define a variable/value for each environment, e.g. "LoggingConnectionStringDev", "LoggingConnectionStringProduction"
   [image]
3. Back in your Process Variables for the Build/Release, make **SURE** you don't have a variable named "LoggingConnectionString", otherwise this will overwrite the value coming from the variable group
4. In your Release process, create a Powershell inline script at the beginning of the Agent with the following code

---

```
Param(
   [string]$LoggingConnectionString
)

Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=LoggingConnectionString]$LoggingConnectionString"
```

5. Pass your variable group as an argument to this inline powershell, e.g.

   -LoggingConnectionString "$(LoggingConnectionStringDev)"

The final powershell step should look something like this: [image]

During release, the powershell will set your process variable from the variable groups.  If powershell isn't an option for you, there are [other options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/_shared/set-variables-in-scripts?tabs=batch)

Comment: This method has now been made obsolete by an actual built-in implementation from Microsoft, see my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48578601/1328993)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to use variable Groups per environment.

As [the user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19056559-make-it-possible-to-link-a-variable-group-to-a-spe) you linked, you can vote and follow up for the suggested feature.

The work around for now is **using environment variables to overwrite the variables in variable Group**.

Assume the variable `LoggingConnectionString` with the value `Server=myDB` in variable group need to be used both for Dev environment and staging environment. But for staging environment, it needs to use another value (such as `Server=stageDB`) from the variable `LoggingConnectionString`. So you can add the an environment variable `LoggingConnectionString` with the value `Server=stageDB` for staging environment.

- When the variable `$(LoggingConnectionString)` is used in Dev environment, it will use the value (`Server=myDB`) defined in variable group.
- When the variable `$(LoggingConnectionString)` is used in staging environment, since the variables both defined in environment variable and variable group, it will use the value (`Server=stageDB`) defined in environment variable.